# How to get values from a XML where the names are the same

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have to create a table from a XML file.

The catch is that every ID can have multiple Rows.

So the table needs to look like this.

| ID | ec_date | ec_description | ec_Type | ec_currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54bd0b6f-693e-476f-a80e-0094de4cf3b4 | 27-July-2021 | Reiskosten woon-werk | XP504 | EUR |
| 9adfe4dd-49be-48fb-a838-009e861be8bd | 24-August-2021 | reiskosten Alkmaar-Zaandam | XP502 | EUR |
| 9adfe4dd-49be-48fb-a838-009e861be8bd | 26-August-2021 | reiskosten Alkmaar-Zaandam | XP502 | EUR |

This is my XML structure:

```
<Root>
  <Data>
    <Data>
      <table>
        <id>{54bd0b6f-693e-476f-a80e-0094de4cf3b4}</id>
        <rows>
          <row>
            <columns>
              <column name="ec_date" value="27-July-2021" type="System.DateTime" />
              <column name="ec_description" value="Reiskosten woon-werk" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_Type" value="XP504" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_currency" value="EUR" type="System.String" />
            </columns>
          </row>
        </rows>
        <key>DefaultKey</key>
        <total>145.14</total>
        <AddOnKey>0</AddOnKey>
        <data />
        <parameters />
      </table>
    </Data>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Data>
      <table>
        <id>{9adfe4dd-49be-48fb-a838-009e861be8bd}</id>
        <rows>
          <row>
            <columns>
              <column name="ec_date" value="24-August-2021" type="System.DateTime" />
              <column name="ec_description" value="reiskosten Alkmaar-Zaandam" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_Type" value="XP502" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_currency" value="EUR" type="System.String" />
            </columns>
          </row>
          <row>
            <columns>
              <column name="ec_date" value="26-August-2021" type="System.DateTime" />
              <column name="ec_description" value="reiskosten Alkmaar-Zaandam" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_Type" value="XP502" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_currency" value="EUR" type="System.String" />
            </columns>
          </row>
        </rows>
        <key>DefaultKey</key>
        <total>8.82</total>
        <AddOnKey>0</AddOnKey>
        <data />
        <parameters />
      </table>
    </Data>
  </Data>
 </Root>
```

So far I've tried this query:

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML = ('<Root>
  <Data>
    <Data>
      <table>
        <id>{54bd0b6f-693e-476f-a80e-0094de4cf3b4}</id>
        <rows>
          <row>
            <columns>
              <column name="ec_date" value="27-July-2021" type="System.DateTime" />
              <column name="ec_description" value="Reiskosten woon-werk" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_Type" value="XP504" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_currency" value="EUR" type="System.String" />
            </columns>
          </row>
        </rows>
        <key>DefaultKey</key>
        <total>145.14</total>
        <AddOnKey>0</AddOnKey>
        <data />
        <parameters />
      </table>
    </Data>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Data>
      <table>
        <id>{9adfe4dd-49be-48fb-a838-009e861be8bd}</id>
        <rows>
          <row>
            <columns>
              <column name="ec_date" value="24-August-2021" type="System.DateTime" />
              <column name="ec_description" value="reiskosten Alkmaar-ZaandamXP502" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_Type" value="XP502" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_currency" value="EUR" type="System.String" />
            </columns>
          </row>
          <row>
            <columns>
              <column name="ec_date" value="26-August-2021" type="System.DateTime" />
              <column name="ec_description" value="reiskosten Alkmaar-Zaandam" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_Type" value="XP502" type="System.String" />
              <column name="ec_currency" value="EUR" type="System.String" />
            </columns>
          </row>
        </rows>
        <key>DefaultKey</key>
        <total>8.82</total>
        <AddOnKey>0</AddOnKey>
        <data />
        <parameters />
      </table>
    </Data>
  </Data>
 </Root>')

SELECT top 2000
    ID = id.value('(table/id)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)'),
    ec_date = ColumnData.value('Column[1]', 'nvarchar(255)')
    ec_description = ColumnData.value('Column[2]', 'nvarchar(255)')


FROM
    @XMLData.nodes('/Root/Data/Data') AS XTbl(id)
CROSS APPLY
    id.nodes('table/rows/row/columns') AS XTbl2(ColumnData)
```

The result is like this:
| ID | ec_date | ec_description |
| -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 54bd0b6f-693e-476f-a80e-0094de4cf3b4 | NULL  | NULL |
| 9adfe4dd-49be-48fb-a838-009e861be8bd | NULL  | NULL |
| 9adfe4dd-49be-48fb-a838-009e861be8bd | NULL  | NULL |

when there are multiple rows linked to an ID it correctly makes multiple rows.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the value from the XML columns.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It will will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

Notable points:

- `OUTER APPLY` simulates parent/child relationship between two levels in the input XML.
- XQuery `.nodes()` method XPath expressions were properly adjusted.
- t1(p) and t2(c) are aliases for parent /child (one-to-many) relational resultsets.
- Advanced `TRIM(...)` function is used to remove curly brackets. That function was introduced in SQL Server 2017.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @XMLData XML = 
N'<Root>
    <Data>
        <Data>
            <table>
                <id>{54bd0b6f-693e-476f-a80e-0094de4cf3b4}</id>
                <rows>
                    <row>
                        <columns>
                            <column name="ec_date" value="27-July-2021"
                                    type="System.DateTime"/>
                            <column name="ec_description"
                                    value="Reiskosten woon-werk"
                                    type="System.String"/>
                            <column name="ec_Type" value="XP504"
                                    type="System.String"/>
                            <column name="ec_currency" value="EUR"
                                    type="System.String"/>
                        </columns>
                    </row>
                </rows>
                <key>DefaultKey</key>
                <total>145.14</total>
                <AddOnKey>0</AddOnKey>
                <data/>
                <parameters/>
            </table>
        </Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <Data>
            <table>
                <id>{9adfe4dd-49be-48fb-a838-009e861be8bd}</id>
                <rows>
                    <row>
                        <columns>
                            <column name="ec_date" value="24-August-2021"
                                    type="System.DateTime"/>
                            <column name="ec_description"
                                    value="reiskosten Alkmaar-ZaandamXP502"
                                    type="System.String"/>
                            <column name="ec_Type" value="XP502"
                                    type="System.String"/>
                            <column name="ec_currency" value="EUR"
                                    type="System.String"/>
                        </columns>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <columns>
                            <column name="ec_date" value="26-August-2021"
                                    type="System.DateTime"/>
                            <column name="ec_description"
                                    value="reiskosten Alkmaar-Zaandam"
                                    type="System.String"/>
                            <column name="ec_Type" value="XP502"
                                    type="System.String"/>
                            <column name="ec_currency" value="EUR"
                                    type="System.String"/>
                        </columns>
                    </row>
                </rows>
                <key>DefaultKey</key>
                <total>8.82</total>
                <AddOnKey>0</AddOnKey>
                <data/>
                <parameters/>
            </table>
        </Data>
    </Data>
</Root>';

SELECT TRIM('{}' FROM p.value('(id/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)')) AS ID
    , c.value('(column[@name="ec_date"]/@value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS ec_date
    , c.value('(column[@name="ec_description"]/@value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS ec_description
    , c.value('(column[@name="ec_Type"]/@value)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS ec_Type
    , c.value('(column[@name="ec_currency"]/@value)[1]', 'CHAR(3)') AS ec_currency
FROM @XMLData.nodes('/Root/Data/Data/table') AS t1(p)
    OUTER APPLY p.nodes('rows/row/columns') AS t2(c);
```

**Output**

```
+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+
|                  ID                  |    ec_date     |         ec_description          | ec_Type | ec_currency |
+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+
| 54bd0b6f-693e-476f-a80e-0094de4cf3b4 | 27-July-2021   | Reiskosten woon-werk            | XP504   | EUR         |
| 9adfe4dd-49be-48fb-a838-009e861be8bd | 24-August-2021 | reiskosten Alkmaar-ZaandamXP502 | XP502   | EUR         |
| 9adfe4dd-49be-48fb-a838-009e861be8bd | 26-August-2021 | reiskosten Alkmaar-Zaandam      | XP502   | EUR         |
+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for , thank you.